# In PHP, how can I get the Outer XML from a DOMNode?

Tags: php, xml

If you have [DOMNode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) in PHP, how can you get the outer xml (i.e. the all of the XML that is inside this element plus the element itself)?

For example, lets say this is the structure

```
<car>
 <tire>Michelin</tire>
 <seats>Leather</seats>
 <type>
   <color>red</color>
   <make>Audi</make>
 </type>
</car>
```

And I have a pointer to the <type> node... I want to get back

```
<type>
    <color>red</color>
    <make>Audi</make>
</type>
```

If I just ask for the text, I get back "redAudi".

Comment: note that you're actually asking for the *outer* xml, since it includes the node itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a DOMDocument:

```
// If you don't have a document already:
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

echo $doc->saveXML($node); // where $node is your DOMNode
```

Check DOMDocument::saveXML in the docs for more info.

When you pass a DOMNode to saveXML() you get back only the contents of that node not the whole document.

Comment: No, I have a DOMNode (a subnode of the DOMDocument) and I need to extract out the InnerXML...

Comment: rojoca is saying that the DOMNode class doesn't have a method to extract the original XML. Instead you need to pass the node to a brand new DOM document to re-encode it as XML.

Comment: this may also work and won’t require the creation of a DOMDocument - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#V86224

Answer (score 13):

After an hour spent, I came up with this (it seems the best solution)

```
$node->ownerDocument->saveXml($node);
```

Comment: The problem is, sometimes a node does not have an owner document. E.g. if it comes from \XMLReader::expand().

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
function getInnerXml(DomNode $node){
  $xml = '';
  foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode){
    $xml .= $node->ownerDocument->saveXml($childNode);
  }
  return $xml;
}
```

Comment: why not just `return $node->ownerDocument->saveXxml($node)` ?

Comment: but like, you know... without the typo.