# return raw XML from xpath query in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm looking to xpath and extract raw XML from a file in PHP, but I'm not looking to parse the result into an array.  I'm simply trying to return a subset from the original document.

My original document is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <row id="1">
        <child1>value1</child1>
        <child2>value1</child2>
        <child3>value1</child3>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
        <child1>value1</child1>
        <child2>value1</child2>
        <child3>value1</child3>
    </row>
</root>
```

All I want to do is be able to xpath into /root/row[@id="1"] and return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<row id="1">
    <child1>value1</child1>
    <child2>value1</child2>
    <child3>value1</child3>
</row>
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You are looking for simplexml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root>...</root>'); // or $doc->load($file) if loading from file
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/root/row[@id='1']");
if ($elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $item) {
        echo $doc->saveXML($item), "\n";
    }
 }
```

thanks to @fab's comment. I forgot [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983564/in-php-how-can-i-get-the-outer-xml-from-a-domnode).

Comment: This returns the entire original document, not the result of the XPATH.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but you need to generate another XML file from the original one.

Comment: No, you just need to pass the node as parameter: `$doc->saveXML($elements->item(0));`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  All I was missing was the $elements->item(0).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a header like this,

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');
```