# DOMDocument removing comments syntax from a fetched file - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, dom, laravel-blade, domdocument

I am using `DOMDocument` to read specific html (body code) from a file (I don't know much about DOMDocument), that file has comments in the code. When i echo the returned html on my page, I can see the comments text on my page, i mean `DOMDocument` playing with comments, it is uncommenting my comments.
**Controller Code:**

```
$file = storage_path('app/public/widgets/' . json_decode($currentWidget->file)->folderName . "/index.php");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
```

**Blade File Code:**

```
@if (!is_null($html))
    @foreach ($html as $element)
        @php $nodes = $element->childNodes; @endphp
        @foreach ($nodes as $node)
            {!! $node->nodeValue !!}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**My real html is like:**
[image]

**But see, it's removing the comments:**
[image]

Does anyone knows the problem? and how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Well that's because you are outputting only the nodeValue of those comment nodes - and the node value of a comment, _is_ the text inside. You neglected to output the actual "tags" for these nodes. If you had `<a href="#">foobar</a>` in your document, and you would only output the nodeValue of that - then you would not get a _link_ either, but just the _text_ `foobar`.

Comment: @CBroe then which attribute I have to use instead of nodeValue?

Comment: There is no "attribute" that contains the whole _code representation_ of the node. This is not JavaScript, where you would have stuff like `outerHTML`. You will need to either create the necessary output yourself, by checking what node type you are dealing with, what tag name it has, etc. - or use an approach that makes use of the `saveXML` method PHP's DOM implementation comes with, https://stackoverflow.com/q/983564/1427878

Comment: @CBroe `saveXML()` works good (I was trying to use it before, it was not working because i was putting it in wrong place). Thanks buddy